# 404 Not Found for geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver after install

Tags: geoserver

I've installed geoserver 2.6.2 on Window 8.1 64 and after install I get a 404 Not Found for geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver. I have checked that nothing else appears to be using port 8080, and I checked that Java used is 7.1.

Below is the log:

```
> 2015-03-03 09:14:12,741 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'burg'
> 2015-03-03 09:14:12,757 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'capitals'
> 2015-03-03 09:14:12,757 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style
> 'cite_lakes' 2015-03-03 09:14:12,757 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded
> style 'dem' 2015-03-03 09:14:12,757 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded
> style 'giant_polygon' 2015-03-03 09:14:12,757 INFO [org.geoserver] -
> Loaded style 'grass' 2015-03-03 09:14:12,757 INFO [org.geoserver] -
> Loaded style 'green' 2015-03-03 09:14:12,757 INFO [org.geoserver] -
> Loaded style 'line' 2015-03-03 09:14:12,757 INFO [org.geoserver] -
> Loaded style 'poi' 2015-03-03 09:14:12,773 INFO [org.geoserver] -
> Loaded style 'point' 2015-03-03 09:14:12,773 INFO [org.geoserver] -
> Loaded style 'polygon' 2015-03-03 09:14:12,773 INFO [org.geoserver] -
> Loaded style 'poly_landmarks' 2015-03-03 09:14:12,773 INFO
> [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'pophatch' 2015-03-03 09:14:12,773 INFO
> [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'population' 2015-03-03 09:14:12,773
> INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'rain' 2015-03-03 09:14:12,773
> INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'raster' 2015-03-03 09:14:12,788
> INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'restricted' 2015-03-03
> 09:14:12,788 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'simple_roads'
> 2015-03-03 09:14:12,788 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style
> 'simple_streams' 2015-03-03 09:14:12,788 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded
> style 'tiger_roads' 2015-03-03 09:14:12,788 WARN [org.geoserver] - No
> default workspace was found. 2015-03-03 09:14:12,788 INFO
> [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'cite' 2015-03-03 09:14:12,835 INFO
> [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'it.geosolutions' 2015-03-03
> 09:14:12,835 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'nurc' 2015-03-03
> 09:14:12,851 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'sde' 2015-03-03
> 09:14:12,851 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'sf' 2015-03-03
> 09:14:12,851 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'tiger'
> 2015-03-03 09:14:12,851 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'topp'
> 2015-03-03 09:14:13,273 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded store
> 'arcGridSample', enabled 2015-03-03 09:14:13,304 INFO [org.geoserver]
> - Loaded coverage store 'arcGridSample' 2015-03-03 09:14:14,756 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'Arc_Sample', enabled 2015-03-03
> 09:14:14,787 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'arcGridSample'
> 2015-03-03 09:14:14,975 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer
> 'Arc_Sample' 2015-03-03 09:14:14,990 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded
> store 'img_sample2', disabled 2015-03-03 09:14:14,990 INFO
> [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'img_sample2' 2015-03-03
> 09:14:15,318 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'Pk50095',
> disabled 2015-03-03 09:14:15,318 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded
> coverage 'img_sample2' 2015-03-03 09:14:15,318 INFO [org.geoserver] -
> Loaded layer 'Pk50095' 2015-03-03 09:14:15,334 INFO [org.geoserver] -
> Loaded store 'mosaic', enabled 2015-03-03 09:14:15,334 INFO
> [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'mosaic' 2015-03-03
> 09:14:15,350 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'mosaic', enabled
> 2015-03-03 09:14:15,350 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage
> 'mosaic' 2015-03-03 09:14:15,990 WARN [imagemosaic.Utils] - Unable to
> find sample image for path C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer
> 2.6.2\data_dir\coverages\mosaic_sample\sample_image 2015-03-03 09:14:15,990 WARN [gce.imagemosaic] - Unable to find sample image for
> path
> file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.6.2/data_dir/coverages/mosaic_sample/mosaic.shp
> 2015-03-03 09:14:16,022 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'mosaic'
> 2015-03-03 09:14:16,022 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded store
> 'worldImageSample', enabled 2015-03-03 09:14:16,037 INFO
> [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'worldImageSample' 2015-03-03
> 09:14:16,037 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'Img_Sample',
> enabled 2015-03-03 09:14:16,037 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage
> 'worldImageSample' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,068 INFO [org.geoserver] -
> Loaded layer 'Img_Sample' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,178 INFO [org.geoserver]
> - Loaded store 'sf', enabled 2015-03-03 09:14:16,178 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'sf' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,240 INFO
> [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'archsites', enabled 2015-03-03
> 09:14:16,256 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'sf'
> 2015-03-03 09:14:16,272 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer
> 'archsites' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,272 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded
> feature type 'bugsites', enabled 2015-03-03 09:14:16,272 INFO
> [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'sf' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,272
> INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'bugsites' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,287
> INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'restricted', enabled
> 2015-03-03 09:14:16,287 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type
> 'sf' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,287 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer
> 'restricted' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,303 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded
> feature type 'roads', enabled 2015-03-03 09:14:16,303 INFO
> [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'sf' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,303
> INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'roads' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,318
> INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'streams', enabled
> 2015-03-03 09:14:16,318 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type
> 'sf' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,318 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer
> 'streams' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,334 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded store
> 'sfdem', enabled 2015-03-03 09:14:16,334 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded
> coverage store 'sfdem' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,334 INFO [org.geoserver] -
> Loaded coverage 'sfdem', enabled 2015-03-03 09:14:16,334 INFO
> [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'sfdem' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,506 INFO
> [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'sfdem' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,506 INFO
> [org.geoserver] - Loaded store 'nyc', enabled 2015-03-03 09:14:16,506
> INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'nyc' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,522
> INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'giant_polygon', enabled
> 2015-03-03 09:14:16,522 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type
> 'nyc' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,522 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer
> 'giant_polygon' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,537 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded
> feature type 'poi', enabled 2015-03-03 09:14:16,537 INFO
> [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'nyc' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,537
> INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'poi' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,537 INFO
> [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'poly_landmarks', enabled
> 2015-03-03 09:14:16,537 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type
> 'nyc' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,537 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer
> 'poly_landmarks' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,553 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded
> feature type 'tiger_roads', enabled 2015-03-03 09:14:16,553 INFO
> [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'nyc' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,553
> INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tiger_roads' 2015-03-03
> 09:14:16,553 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded store 'states_shapefile',
> enabled 2015-03-03 09:14:16,568 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data
> store 'states_shapefile' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,568 INFO [org.geoserver]
> - Loaded feature type 'states', enabled 2015-03-03 09:14:16,568 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'states_shapefile' 2015-03-03
> 09:14:16,584 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'states' 2015-03-03
> 09:14:16,600 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded store 'taz_shapes', enabled
> 2015-03-03 09:14:16,600 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store
> 'taz_shapes' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,615 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded
> feature type 'tasmania_cities', enabled 2015-03-03 09:14:16,615 INFO
> [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'taz_shapes' 2015-03-03
> 09:14:16,631 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tasmania_cities'
> 2015-03-03 09:14:16,631 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type
> 'tasmania_roads', enabled 2015-03-03 09:14:16,631 INFO [org.geoserver]
> - Loaded feature type 'taz_shapes' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,631 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tasmania_roads' 2015-03-03
> 09:14:16,647 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type
> 'tasmania_state_boundaries', enabled 2015-03-03 09:14:16,647 INFO
> [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'taz_shapes' 2015-03-03
> 09:14:16,709 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer
> 'tasmania_state_boundaries' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,709 INFO
> [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tasmania_water_bodies', enabled
> 2015-03-03 09:14:16,709 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type
> 'taz_shapes' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,709 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded
> layer 'tasmania_water_bodies' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,725 INFO
> [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'spearfish' 2015-03-03
> 09:14:16,725 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'tasmania'
> 2015-03-03 09:14:16,725 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group
> 'tiger-ny' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,803 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder]
> - ************************************************************************************************************************************************** 2015-03-03 09:14:16,803 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - ***
> Found Java environment variable GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR set to C:\Program
> Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.6.2\data_dir, using it as the default prefix.
> *** 2015-03-03 09:14:16,803 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - ************************************************************************************************************************************************** 2015-03-03 09:14:16,803 INFO [config.XMLConfiguration] - Will look for
> geowebcache.xml in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer
> 2.6.2\data_dir\gwc' 2015-03-03 09:14:16,990 INFO [gwc.layer] - Initializing GWC configuration based on GeoServer's Catalog 2015-03-03
> 09:14:16,990 INFO [gwc.layer] - GeoServer TileLayer store base
> directory is: C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer
> 2.6.2\data_dir\gwc-layers 2015-03-03 09:14:17,006 INFO [gwc.layer] - Loading tile layers from C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer
> 2.6.2\data_dir\gwc-layers 2015-03-03 09:14:17,022 INFO [gwc.layer] - GWC configuration based on GeoServer's Catalog loaded successfuly
> 2015-03-03 09:14:17,022 INFO [layer.TileLayerDispatcher] -
> Configuration GeoServer Catalog Configuration contained no layers.
> 2015-03-03 09:14:17,022 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - Found no
> configuration file in config directory, will create one at 'C:\Program
> Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.6.2\data_dir\gwc\geowebcache.xml' from
> template
> jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.6.2/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gwc-core-1.6.1.jar!/geowebcache_empty.xml
> 2015-03-03 09:14:17,100 INFO [config.XMLConfiguration] - Configuration
> file validated fine. 2015-03-03 09:14:17,115 INFO
> [config.XMLConfiguration] - Initializing GridSets from C:\Program
> Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.6.2\data_dir\gwc 2015-03-03 09:14:17,115 INFO
> [config.XMLConfiguration] - Initializing layers from C:\Program Files
> (x86)\GeoServer 2.6.2\data_dir\gwc 2015-03-03 09:14:17,115 INFO
> [layer.TileLayerDispatcher] - Configuration C:\Program Files
> (x86)\GeoServer 2.6.2\data_dir\gwc contained no layers. 2015-03-03
> 09:14:17,162 INFO [diskquota.ConfigLoader] - DiskQuota configuration
> not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer
> 2.6.2\data_dir\gwc\geowebcache-diskquota.xml 2015-03-03 09:14:17,178 INFO [diskquota.ConfigLoader] - DiskQuota configuration not found:
> C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer
> 2.6.2\data_dir\gwc\geowebcache-diskquota.xml 2015-03-03 09:14:17,178 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Setting up disk quota periodic
> enforcement task 2015-03-03 09:14:17,178 INFO
> [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - 0 layers configured with their own
> quotas.  2015-03-03 09:14:17,178 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - 0
> layers attached to global quota 500.0 MB 2015-03-03 09:14:17,209 INFO
> [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Disk quota periodic enforcement task
> set up every 10 SECONDS 2015-03-03 09:14:17,287 INFO [org.geoserver] -
> Loaded service 'wcs', enabled 2015-03-03 09:14:17,318 INFO
> [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'wfs', enabled 2015-03-03
> 09:14:17,350 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'wms', enabled
> 2015-03-03 09:14:17,365 INFO [gwc.config] - Initializing GeoServer
> specific GWC configuration from gwc-gs.xml 2015-03-03 09:14:17,897
> INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/gwc/service/**] onto
> handler 'dispatcher' 2015-03-03 09:14:17,943 INFO
> [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Invoked setServletPrefix(gwc)
> 2015-03-03 09:14:17,959 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller] - Initializing
> GeoRSS poller in a background job... 2015-03-03 09:14:18,100 INFO
> [rest.RESTDispatcher] - Created RESTDispatcher with 14 paths
> 2015-03-03 09:14:18,147 INFO [wms.WMSService] - Will NOT recombine
> tiles for non-tiling clients. 2015-03-03 09:14:18,147 INFO
> [wms.WMSService] - Will proxy requests to backend that are not getmap
> or getcapabilities. 2015-03-03 09:14:18,240 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller]
> - No enabled GeoRSS feeds found, poller will not run. 2015-03-03 09:14:19,365 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/kml]
> onto handler 'dispatcher' 2015-03-03 09:14:19,365 INFO
> [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/kml/*] onto handler
> 'dispatcher' 2015-03-03 09:14:19,365 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] -
> Mapped URL path [/kml/icon/**/*] onto handler 'kmlIconService'
> 2015-03-03 09:14:19,490 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path
> [/ows/**] onto handler 'dispatcher' 2015-03-03 09:14:19,490 INFO
> [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/ows] onto handler
> 'dispatcher' 2015-03-03 09:14:19,506 INFO [org.geoserver] - GeoServer
> configuration lock is enabled 2015-03-03 09:14:19,631 INFO
> [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/wcs] onto handler
> 'dispatcher' 2015-03-03 09:14:19,631 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] -
> Mapped URL path [/wcs/**] onto handler 'dispatcher' 2015-03-03
> 09:14:20,860 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/wfs/*]
> onto handler 'dispatcher' 2015-03-03 09:14:20,860 INFO
> [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/TestWfsPost] onto handler
> 'wfsTestServlet' 2015-03-03 09:14:20,875 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping]
> - Mapped URL path [/wfs] onto handler 'dispatcher' 2015-03-03 09:14:26,266 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/wms/*]
> onto handler 'dispatcher' 2015-03-03 09:14:26,266 INFO
> [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/wms] onto handler
> 'dispatcher' 2015-03-03 09:14:26,344 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] -
> Mapped URL path [/animate] onto handler 'dispatcher' 2015-03-03
> 09:14:26,344 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path
> [/animate/*] onto handler 'dispatcher' 2015-03-03 09:14:26,454 INFO
> [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache Initialized with 1000 Max
> Entries, 300 seconds idle time, 600 seconds time to live and 3
> concurrency level 2015-03-03 09:14:26,454 INFO [geoserver.security] -
> AuthenticationCache Eviction Task created to run every 600 seconds
> 2015-03-03 09:14:27,016 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start reloading
> user/grous for service named default 2015-03-03 09:14:27,016 INFO
> [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service
> named default
```

Comment: Log should continue like `2015-03-03 14:40:06.343::INFO:  Opened C:\programs\geoserver-2.7-RC1\logs\2015_0
3_03.request.log
2015-03-03 14:40:07.433::INFO:  Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080` 
I suppose that GeoServer has troubles with initializing the log file. May be due to access denied in the subdirectory of program files. Try a workaround by installing into some normal directory like c:\programs\geoserver.

Comment: OK - while I had said that nothing else was using port 8080, I just found out that for http://localhost:8080/ I see pgadmin is using it: Apache - version 2.4.7
PHP - version 5.4.23. How can I change the port (basic steps needed as I am a basic user here...)?

Comment: Check your bin\startup.bat file, or the etc\jetty.xml file - depending on how you start GeoServer